# "Оттесченный" or "оттестенный"?

Tags: выбор-слова, информатика

There is a word `тестировать` in modern Russian which differs from `проверять`/`испытывать` (both of these has wider meaning). This word has also colloquial form `тестить`.
I want to ask, regarding de-facto existing rules of word formation in Russian, which derived adjective is more appropriate: `оттесченный` (or even  `оттесщенный` compare to `обесчестить`/`обесчещенный`) or `оттестенный`? Or may be some other form? Why?

Comment: The verb _to test_ in this sense better correspond to the russian verb _испытывать_. Not a single inspection, as _проверка_ implies, but a series of thorough tests, or _испытаний_.

Comment: @theUg, valid note, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the word `тестить` is colloquial and kind of funny it would be logical to use `оттестенный`.

Saying "logical" I mean that the word `оттестенный` needs to break some rules to be funny.

`Оттесченный` may be more proper by the rules, but it sounds to me as if it is derived from the verb `чесать` somehow. As if somebody wanted to say `отчесанный` but misspoke. :-)

Comment: I think that «оттесченный» is good enough because «сч» is read as «щ».

Answer (score 9):

The word you are looking for is *протестированный*. If you want to sound a little more formal, *прошедший тестирование* is for you.

Comment: Not exactly, since you are talking about adjective derived from "full" term  - "тестировать". And I wonder how do I derive adjective from the colloquial "тестировать". Because, well, such ajdective is used real life )))

Comment: @shabunc: you meant "how do I derive adjective from the colloquial "тестить"".

Comment: You can delete and retype the whole comment if nobody answered yet :-).

Comment: @shabunc But you can say "I have already can" - is it OK?

Comment: no, guys, hard day's night for poor non-native speaker, sorry for annoying you with such harsh grammar errors.

Comment: Thoroughly formal would be _прошедший испытания_.

Answer (score 3):

At work I can say: Те́стить(imperfect) → Проте́стить(perfect) → Проте́щенный(derived adjective) and coworkers will understand me.

Probably, grammatically more correct is протеСЩенный or протеСТЩенный, but it's hard to pronounce, in colloquial speech it shorten to single "щ".

Answer (score 2):

I think that "оттестированный" (compare to "ремонтировать"/"отремонтированный") would be a better choice.